# Display html file stored in unix system on a web browser

Tags: html, unix

I have a Unix Shell Script which generates an HTML file as output. This file has to be displayed on a web browser. Whenever the page is refreshed, the script should be executed automatically and the page should be loaded with fresh values. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a CGI program.

Make sure it outputs an HTTP content type header, any other headers you want, and two blank lines before the rest of your content.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
# etc etc
```

Then consult the manual for your HTTP server to find out how to configure it to execute CGI programs.